# What's the tone on 河南话's 中 (as in: very good)

Tags: pronunciation, topolect

What's the time on 河南话's 中 meaning very good?

It sounds like 3rd tone but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in a localism it's hard to say a word's pronunciation is first or second or third or fourth tone. Cause sometimes the localism pronunciation is out of the four kinds of tone. In this question, if I have to choose one from the four tones,it would be third tone.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the 2nd tone. My wife is from there so I think she has the authority on that...

Answer (score 0):

"中" sounds like 3rd and often means “OK” or "好"，"好的"